# Android webView setUserAgentString effecting video stream

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-webview

I am using webview for webrtc streaming application.
I noticed when i define setUserAgentString video is working fine but if i remove it or change to any other value html5 video player not showing video (only audio).

It only work for string  "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36"
If i changed to any other value or remove its not working.

Testing in Android 9 and 10 having chrome 81 version and updated system webview

My question is there any relation of user agent string with webview functionality or its just for information that which browser is using?